# Is it possible to align the <p> to make them even?

Tags: html, css

How can I make that [image: Before]

To look like that: [image]

I mean the second column is even in every category.
My code looks like that:

````
                <div class="prod-card-fields-static col-5">
                    {[if_manufacturer]}
                    <p class="m-0">{[lang_manufacturer]}: <b>{[manufacturer]}</b></p>
                    {[/if_manufacturer]}
                    {[if_custom_field_1]}
                    <p class="m-0">{[custom_field_1_name]}: <b>{[custom_field_1]}</b></p>
                    {[/if_custom_field_1]}
                    {[if_custom_field_2]}
                    <p class="m-0">{[custom_field_2_name]}: <b>{[custom_field_2]}</b></p>
                    {[/if_custom_field_2]}
                    {[if_custom_field_3]}
                    <p class="m-0">{[custom_field_3_name]}: <b>{[custom_field_3]}</b></p>
                    {[/if_custom_field_3]}
                    {[if_category_1]}
                    <p class="m-0">{[category_1_name]}: <b>{[category_1]}</b></p>
                    {[/if_category_1]}
                    {[if_category_2]}
                    <p class="m-0">{[category_2_name]}: <b>{[category_2]}</b></p>
                    {[/if_category_2]}
                    {[if_category_3]}
                    <p class="m-0">{[category_3_name]}: <b>{[category_3]}</b></p>
                    {[/if_category_3]}
                </div>
                
            </div>```
````

Comment: Have you tried using a `<table>`? This qualifies as tabular data, so a table is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your `p` tag in a `div` and give `flexbox` feature to your `div`.

```css
.labelWrapper {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  }
```

```html
<div class="prod-card-fields-static col-5"> 
      <div class="labelWrapper">
                    <p class="m-0">lang_manufacturer: </p>
                    <p>manufacturer</p> 
      </div>
      
      <div class="labelWrapper">
                    <p class="m-0">lang_manufacturer: </p>
                    <p>manufacturer</p> 
      </div>
      
      <div class="labelWrapper">
                    <p class="m-0">lang_manufacturer: </p>
                    <p>manufacturer</p> 
      </div>
                     
</div>
```

Comment: would be easier and more adaptive to solve this with CSS-Grid. Wouldnt require to change the HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

You have different possibilities to solve this problem.

Older/classic one will be to try with HTML tables. In this case you will have a table with two colums. It look to me that you can rely on this solution. Anyway, is also the most rigid way to solve the issue and it can create problems if you have your table to be responsive.
With HTML table your code will have to be formatted like:

```
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
<th>Element of 1th the column, 1st line</th>
<td>Element of 2nd the column, 1st line</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Element of the 1th column, 2nd line</th>
<td>Element of the 2nd column, 2nd line</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

if you want to do this with CSS, you can recour to differents solution as well:

- FLOAT property [Here's a link to float property on W3c](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp)
- you can play with the DISPLAY proterty, giving your element the value Flex for example here's the [w3school link about display property and its values](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) and [the complete guide on flexbox by Chris Coyier](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
- CSS Grid. If you ever used bootstrap you may be familiar with grids, if not here's [a guide about CSS grids by Chris House](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)